# Homemade plain yogurt

Tags: flavor, yogurt

I want to make an homemade plain yogurt,I heard you have to use your leftover yogurt to make some at home.Can I use sweetened yogurt to make my homemade yogurt or is it compulsory to use the plain yogurt that is normally recommended?

Answer (score 7):

The leftover yogurt must contain live and active cultures. It does not matter whether the leftover yogurt is sweetened or not.